# Change the HTML5 left navigation button title in Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I am Using titanium classic for my HTML5 application. I would like to change the left navigation button having a title "Back" to the title "Cancel". I have tried to update the button using "leftNavButton" property, but of no use. Can any one please let me know how to change the text.

Thanks,
Swathi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post a sample of your code?

Typically you need to add a Ti.UI.Button with the attributes you want (plus event handler), then assign this to the Window.leftNavButton property.

So:

```
var button = Ti.UI.createButton({title:'Cancel'});

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
 // handle it here
});

// assuming you have the window in 'win' variable
win.leftNavButton = button;
```